# Java Connection reset exception but working with postman

Tags: apache-commons-httpclient, connection-reset

I suddenly started to get a connection reset exception with an api that I have been communicating with for 4 years. The server provider is telling me that he didn't change anything and I didn't either. Whats weird is that I get a success response when I call the same api on postman. I have even tried python to call it but I get the same error.

http client to call the api

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


    client.getHttpConnectionManager().
    getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
    client.getHttpConnectionManager().
    getParams().setSoTimeout(60000);

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(smsUrl);

    method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[] { 
            new NameValuePair("username", user), 
            new NameValuePair("password", pass), 
            new NameValuePair("action", "sendsms"), 
            new NameValuePair("from", "Sender"),
            new NameValuePair("to", toMobile), 
            new NameValuePair("text", textBody)
    });

    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
            String responseBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

        }



    } catch (HttpException e) {
        System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Release the connection.
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Error stacktrace

```
Fatal transport error: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:827)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1975)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced similar problem. But solved when upgrading client JDK from 7 to 8.
[Ref link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2624)